# Refactor:laravel controller array

Tags: arrays, laravel, database, eloquent, datatable

```
protected $status = array(
        'sale' => [
            'background' => 'bg-info-light',
            'color' => 'text-info'
        ],
        'completed' => [
            'background' => 'bg-success-light',
            'color' => 'text-success'
        ],
    );
```

I have defined array, and

```
$background = $this->code_status[$status]['background'];
            $color = $this->code_status[$status]['color'];
            return "<span class='fw-semibold d-inline-block py-1 px-3 rounded-pill " . $background . " " . $color . "'>$status</span>";
```

Used this is datatable, But I have 20 more status , and have todefine for each of them, My controller will the much lengthy if continue writing 20 array, How can I rewrite this in better way ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, How about using locale?

This is my personal solutions when I make web admin pages, or service pages.

for example
'resources/lang/ko/my_resource.php'

```
<?php

return  [
        'background' => [
            'status' => [
                'sale' => 'bg-info-light',
                'completed' => 'bg-success-light',
            ]
            ],
        'color' => [
            'status' => [
                'sale' => 'text-info',
                'completed' => 'text-success',
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

and, Your view file...

```
 @foreach(collect(['sale', 'complete']) as $status)
  <span class="fw-semibold d-inline-block py-1 px-3 rounded-pill {{ __('my_resource.background.staus.'.$status) }} {{ __('my_resource.color.status.'.$status) }}">{{ strtoupper($status) }}</span>
  @endforeach
```

But, be careful setting your locale and locale files.

Sorry of my poor language. This is my first post in stackoverflow.